# htaccess rule not working when adding slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

My main domain points to `/html` folder which has nothing in it but a `.htaccess` file.

I have a CodeIgniter website in `/html/manage` folder.

This is htaccess file content

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^pg/(.*)$ /manage/product_groups [L,QSA]
```

This does not work, it shows 404 error page of codeigniter.

(If I visit website.com/manage/product_groups directly from browser, it works fine)

If I do `RewriteRule ^pg/(.*)$ /manage [L,QSA]` then it works fine, actually this page has login page of CI.

My main goal is to redirect every request redirect from `website.com/pg/` to 
`website.com/manage/product_groups`

Comment: you checked that product_groups exists and has right permission?

Comment: @Shiping Yes, I told `(If I visit website.com/manage/product_groups directly from browser, it works fine)` ... I have set a test message at that URL and it shows if I visit it from browser directly

Comment: @Shiping Also notice `If I do RewriteRule ^pg/(.*)$ /manage [L,QSA] then it works fine, actually this page has login page of CI.`

Comment: sorry i missed what you said at one place and misunderstood what you said at the second place.

Comment: What about doing it in the routes table? Like `$route['pg'] = 'manage/product_groups';` or `$route['pg/(:any)'] = 'manage/product_groups';`

Comment: @ourmandave really nice idea ... Can you post a detailed answer on it? I would not use htaccess if your answer works

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know if you had a special case or not.

Just referring to the [routing doc examples](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html#examples).

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

$route['pg'] = 'manage/product_groups';
```

or

```
$route['pg/(:any)'] = 'manage/product_groups';
```

Might have to experiment a bit.